# How to get the top visible section header index in a UITableView of empty sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a list with over 1000 sections that may be empty, meaning `numberOfRows` is 0 for every section.

Is there a way to get the index of the top most visible section?

Please **do not tell me about `indexPathsForVisibleRows`**, this only returns an IndexPath if `numberOfRows` is not 0. Hence, it does not work in this scenario. (Neither does `indexPathsForRows(in:)`)

EDIT: The use case is a calendar view, that can be filtered. Usually, when scrolling up or down, the first visible section defines the header title. In the attached screenshot you see the problem.

[image: Screenshot of a bug in the calendar view]

Comment: so, you would like to see TUESDAY, 25. DECEMBER 2018 instead of February? is that right?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: do you have your code on some repository that I can check?